# Strong, weak and unowned self in closures explanation

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I need some explanation about references in closures in Swift.
Here is my use case, let's imagine we have :

```
class A {...}
class B {

  func makeAclosure() {
   let instanceA = A()
   instanceA.someFunctionA(completion: {(input) in 
     self.someAnotherFunction(input)
   })
  }
}
```

**Is there a retain cycle between class A and B or not ? 
In which case it can be a retain cycle in this kind of scenario ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to say without looking at `A.someFunctionA` since it's unknown if `completion` is `@escaping` (e.g. if it's retained). For the rest of the answer I will assume that it is `@escaping`.

Swift needs to ensure runtime safety, and will keep any objects it might need in the future alive, in this case by making a strong reference to `self` (since `self` is the only variable used inside the closure).

**In this scenario there is no reference cycle**. This is because `instanceA` is not retained, so A => B, but B !=> A.

However, if `instanceA` was retained by `B` (let's say you create an `instanceA: A` property and set it) then you will have a retain cycle.

To get around this you can make variables within the closure either `weak` or `unowned`. They both do the same thing, but provide you with slightly different types. They both hold a weak reference, meaning that `instanceA` will not be increase the reference count of your `B` instance; if `B` is deallocated and there are no other reference, `instanceA` is also deallocated.

When using `[weak self]` `self` is `optional`, e.g. `self: B?`. However, `[unowned self]` is explicitly unwrapped, e.g. `self: B!`. This means that if the closure is called and `self` is `nil` your program will crash. This is why it's important to only use `unowned` when you know for certain that deallocating `B` will also deallocate `A`. There are a few scenarios where `unowned` is safe, e.g. the case when creating a closure and storing it on the same object that created it, but there are more nuances to this.

**If unsure, use `weak`**!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Just to confirm, so when I create an instanceA : A inside a function of class B, it's only considered in the context of the function and not a reference of the class ? The only way to make a strong reference is to make instanceA: A a property of class B ? And another question, if i don't put @escaping, the closure doesn't retain self ?

Comment: Yes, in this case `instanceA` is only kept in memory until it is no longer referenced anywhere, which is once `makeAclosure` finished executing. Yes, the only way to stop `instanceA` being deallocated is to keep a strong reference to it, such as setting it as a property of `B`. If you don't put `@escaping` the compiler will not allow you to store the closure that's passed in. Start without `@escaping` and wait for the compiler to complain!

Answer (score 2):

If your `self` object will potentially be deallocated before your closure is called, you should specify `[weak self]`, so that you can avoid bad access exceptions.

If you know that it will *definitely* not be deallocated, then you can use `[unowned self]` to create a reference that will behave like an implicitly unwrapped optional.

In your example, the instance of `B` owns the reference to `instanceA` (within the context of your `makeAClosure()` function), so you will not end up with a retain cycle.

You should consider the implementation of `someFunctionA(completion:)`, to determine if you need an `unowned` or a `weak` reference to `self` in that closure.

---

*(A small aside: if you're using `[weak self]`, then to avoid having optionals such as `self?` throughout your code, you can use `` guard let `self` = self else { ... } `` to continue using `self` in the closure code.*

Comment: This is incorrect. In this case you would not have a retain cycle because the constant instanceA is created inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Just to confirm, so when I create an instanceA : A inside a function of class B, it's only considered in the context of the function and not a reference of the class ? The only way to make a strong reference is to make instanceA: A a property of class B ?

Comment: @Alex Oops! I'll edit the answer to remove that section.
The rest of it is still valid, so I will leave it there.

Comment: Great! No worries apart from that your answer was excellent :)